# .each on array being overridden when assigning a new value to each element of the array, Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a small program

```
puts "enter segments: "
entry = gets.chomp.split


entry.each do |value|
    @new_values = []
    if value == "0"
        value = 2
        @new_values << value
    elsif value == "1"
        value = 3
        @new_values << value
    elsif value == "2"
        value = 1
        @new_values << value
    elsif value == "3"
        value = 2
        @new_values << value
    elsif value == "4"
        value = 3
        @new_values << value
    elsif value == "5"
        value = 2
        @new_values << value
    elsif value == "6"
        value = 3
        @new_values << value
    elsif value == "7"
        value = 3
        @new_values << value
    end
end

print @new_values
```

This program takes user input, splits it up on whitespace and then runs through and assigns an integer value to that replaces the current string.

The problem I am having is that the `value = variable` gets overridden each time a new element of the array passes through. How can I set this up so that all of the values are reassigned and entered into the `@new_values` array?

Comment: Move `@new_values = []` before the loop.

Comment: thank you @MladenJablanović

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @MladenJablanović suggested, you need to move `@new_values = []` outside of your loop.

```
@new_values = []
entry.each do |value|
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I know there's already an accepted answer but how bout a little cleanup on your massive if else block?

```
puts "enter segments: "
entry = gets.chomp.split

@dict = [2,3,1,2,3,2,3,3]
new_values = entry.map do |value|
  @dict[value.to_i]
end

print new_values
```